# Unable to use rules to update field after the first update

Tags: rules, users

I currently have a field that shows the last updated date on a user edit page.

I'm using the current configuration for rules.

```
Event:
    After updating an existing user account
    After saving a new user account

Conditions
    Entity has field
      Parameter: Entity: [account], Field: field_last_updated

Actions
    Set a data value
      Paremter: Data: [account:field_last_updated], Value: now
```

It works great the first time but subsequent updates do not update the last_updated field with the current time. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure the rule is getting to the action on subsequent calls - set a dummy system message as the first action - that will help narrow down the problem

Comment: Does adding an action of "Save entity" help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appeared to be that the 'last updated time' field was updating only in 15 minute increments. Though I'm still not sure why it is in 15 minutes increments or how to turn that off.

Comment: You need to look deeper into that. That sounds like a weird caching issue. Make sure that the rule is only changing the account that is being updated, not other accounts.